# delete objects from array when their path property equals object in another array

Tags: powershell

I have an `$array` of `PSCustomObjects` which contain a path,days,filter and recurse property

I `Test-Path` the path of each `PSCustomObject` and if it's `false`, I save only the path in another variable like `$failpath`

Now I want to remove all Objects inside `$array` when the path is inside `$failpath`

I tried things like the `.remove()` method for the `$array`, but that doesn't work and gave me this error (example pic from web): https://i0.wp.com/www.sapien.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/image8.png

So I tried creating a new array, but it's giving me a hard time because I don't know how to iterate over the failpaths correctly. so that each correct objects only gets sent to the new array once (when I tried it, the correct object was there multiple times) - i can't show you the code for this because I already edited it too many times and now it's just a mess.

this is how `$array` and `$faultypath` look like

```
$array = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{
        path    = "\\server\daten\Alle Adressen\Dokumente 70"
        filter  = "*.pdf"
        days    = "90"
        recurse = "false"
    }
    [pscustomobject]@{
        path    = "\\server\Tobit\itacom\ERP2UMS"
        filter  = "*.fax"
        days    = "7"
        recurse = "false"
    }
)

[string[]]$faultypath = @()
$pfade | % { if (!(Test-Path $_.path)) { $faultypath += $_.path } }
```

How can I substract everything which is in `$faultypath` from `$array`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For PowerShell 3 or higher

```
$faultyPath = $pfade | Where-Object { -not (Test-Path $_.Path) } | ForEach-Object Path
$array | Where-Object Path -notin $faultyPath
```

For PowerShell 2 or lower

```
$faultyPath = $pfade | Where-Object { -not (Test-Path $_.Path) } | ForEach-Object { $_.Path }
$array | Where-Object { $faultyPath -notcontains $_.Path }
```

This is potentially an expensive array comparison if both sets are large. In that case dictionaries or hashtables will provide better performance for the comparison.

Comment: Or use `$array = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList, it allows for .add(<item>) and .remove(<item>)`

Comment: `System.Collections.Generic.List[string]` would be slightly faster

Comment: thank you very much Chris, works perfectly. @MathiasR.Jessen if i'd take your approch, would my variables look like this?:  `System.Collections.Generic.List[string]$faultypath = "xy","xy2"` doesn't it have to be `[string[]]`?

Comment: @SimonS `[System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$faultypath = "xy","xy2"` no, the collection type just needs to implement the `ICollection` or `IEnumerable` interfaces, it doesn't *have* to be a simple array